# Finding (e,d) in RSA - mathematical problem

Tags: algorithms, cryptography

I've been trying to solve that but it seems to me illogical.  
$p$ and $q$ are large prime numbers and $n=p*q$.
Alice wants to send Bob message $M$ using RSA.
Alice lets Eve choose the keys for her and makes sure that $e \ mod[φ(n)] ≠ 1$. 
I need to show how Eve could choose a pair of keys $(e,d)$, such that it would be possible to encrypt and decrypt, but 
$M^e \ mod(n)=M \ mod(n)   \ \ \ ∀M$



When I tried to solved that myself, my answers always lead me to $e=1$ which is not possible because $e \ mod[φ(n)] ≠ 1$. 
I will be glad for some help. 
Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, the setting of this question is a bit nonsensical: in RSA encryption, the sender (i.e. Alice) is only supposed to know the public key. But if Alice knows $\varphi(n)$ and $e$, she can trivially calculate $d = e^{-1} \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ and thus learn Bob's private key (or something equivalent to it). If Bob trusts Alice (and Eve, and the connection used to transfer the keys!) enough to share his private RSA key with her like that, it would be easier for them to just share a key for a symmetric cryptosystem like AES and use that instead of RSA.

Comment: … But it would easy enough to fix that issue, e.g. by replacing "Alice lets Eve" with "Bob lets Eve". It's fine for Bob to know $\varphi(n)$ (and $e$), and indeed he would normally learn that (or something equivalent) during key generation.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$$ [isn't necessary for RSA to work](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43198/rsa-keypair-generation-with-bouncy-castle-provider-ed%cf%86n-not-equal-to-one/43208#43208). The [actual necessary and sufficient condition](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33676/why-do-we-need-eulers-totient-function-varphin-in-rsa/33679#33679) is that $$ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\lambda(n)},$$ where $\lambda(n) = \operatorname{lcm}(p-1, q-1) = \varphi(n) \mathbin/ \operatorname{gcd}(p-1, q-1)$ is the [Carmichael totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of $n = pq$.

In particular, since $p$ and $q$ are both odd primes by definition, we know that $\operatorname{gcd}(p-1, q-1) > 1$ and thus that $\lambda(n) < \varphi(n)$.  Thus, it's sufficient for Eve to choose (for example) $e = \lambda(n)+1$ and $d = 1$, which will pass Alice's check for $e \not\equiv 1 \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ even though $m^e \equiv m \pmod{n}$ for all $m$.

Comment: $e = \lambda(n)+1 =  1 \bmod \varphi(n)$, so actually you are suggesting $e=d=1$.

Comment: @kelalaka: It's not. $\varphi(n) \equiv 0 \pmod{\lambda(n)}$, but not the other way around.